# overflow-y inside iframe

Tags: css, iframe, height, overflow

**What I am trying to achieve is to have a scrollable, auto-re-sizable div inside an iframe.**

The problem is that iframe, unlike a div, has a scroll in itself, therefore the overflow-y property of my div is ignored, and entire content of my div is displayed, instead of a just a small portion.

The best explanation is a sample, which you can view by clicking 
http://www.alocet.com/VictorsTestFolder/Sample/Default.html

When I've added CSS "html,body,form{ height:100%; margin:0px; padding:0px;}" to IFrame page, it almost worked, but unfortunately I wasn't able to get rid of duplicate scroll-bars.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say that you can't really do the thing you want to do without JavaScript.

Divs just don't work like that.  They typically overflow as far as needed, spilling wherever.  The only way to keep a div from being sized according to its contents (I'm speaking on experience) is to give it an explicit height.  Otherwise, it will either spill out of its container or, if its container is its own [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/block_formatting_context), cause its container to start scrolling.

The iframe appears to be its own context.  Thus, you MUST set an explicit height if you want the div it contains to keep itself compact.  Two options I see:

You can add a parameter for the server to change the page's height:

```
<iframe src="Default_files/IFrame2.htm?h=400"
```

<s>Then, create a containing div for the whole page with a fixed height that fits within the iframe.  Everything inside of it should flow properly.</s>  Then, set the div that might have a lot of content to a fixed size.

The other option is to use JavaScript, which I think can obtain exactly the variables you're looking for using document.documentElement.clientWidth. [See this article for more details](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html).  Even in this case, you still end up setting the framed page to a fixed height.

Both methods are sketchy workarounds, but I'm somewhat confident you can't do what you want with just CSS.

Comment: I'll try your suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

whats wrong with your 3rd example? you have a fixed size iframe and the div inside still has a scroll bar.

Also what do you mean by scrollable, auto-re-sizable div surely if it is auto resizing it won't be having a scroll bar?

otherwise I'd suggest using a div inside a div and you will have a lot more control and your content will still be showing on search engines.

Comment: Yes, and using Ajax or some sort of server side include will still give him the ability to have the "iframe" effect of using an external page with the content.

Comment: Hi, thank you for response. I don't like the third example, because the height for a div is defined in pixels, not percentages. The problem is in my real project, the iframe can be re-sized, so if iframe will become 200 pixels instead of 400 pixels I've originally defined, part of the div content will get hidden.

Comment: By scrollable and auto-re-sizable, I mean the following: If IFrame is 400 pixels in height, then div, shouldn't be larger than 400 pixels. But because the content of the div may not fit in 400 pixels, I want the div to have a scroll bar (like I had in 3rd example of my sample)

Comment: Also, I want to use iframe, instead of div (which is of course easier to use), because the same web page will be used in several places, and copy-pasting code to several places is not a way to go.

Answer (score 0):

So implementation of a simple javascript that executes onload solved my problem... well, partially, since if you have a table inside a fixed height div, it goes over the specified div height... so I am trying to find a solution for this problem now...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <style type="text/css">
            html, body, form
            {
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
            }

        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            window.onresize = doResize;
            window.onload = doResize;
            function doResize() {
                document.getElementById("popupHeight").style.height = (window.innerHeight - 40) + 'px';
            }
        </script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="popupHeight">
            Text before the div
            <br />
            <div runat="server" id="tblTabGroups" style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 100%;">
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            scrollable<br />
            </div>
            Text after the div
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It seems that in the case with tables, the solution you will need to implement is this one: http://www.oasections.com/articles/scrollabletable.html